# How to restore SearchKit searches lost on upgrade from 5.46.3 to 5.57.3

Tags: upgrade, searchkit

This is a WordPress 6.1.1 site. During the upgrade from 5.46.3 to 5.57.3 (using `cv`), errors came up re table `civicrm_search_segment` not existing, as in this [comment on issue: Upgrader - Apply extension updates after core updates](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3490#note_81122). Tried running the extension database updates separately before or after with `cv` & eventually succeeded running these from the UI.

Table `civicrm_search_segment` was created but is empty. Before the upgrade there were about a dozen SearchKit saved searches, afterwards none show in the UI. Same result from multiple attempts.

Tried exporting a search from a copy of the pre-upgrade 5.46.3 site & importing into the upgraded 5.57.3 site. This failed with the following error displayed on the import dialog: *Unsupported API action: only "save" is allowed.*

Tried changing the API method in the pasted export code from "create" to "save", it then gave a different message: *No records to import.*

Any suggestions for how to restore the missing SearchKit searches?

Answer (score 1):

The answer in this case turned out to be to update the [Entity tables list](https://civicrm.org/extensions/entity-tables-list) extension from version 1.1 to 1.2 - the searches then reappeared.